# Pandas/Jupyter - Using .contains() - Can only use .str accessor with string values

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

So I'm doing an assignment on Jupyter Notebook using pandas.

The point is to adjust a DF column that contains degree info on personnel. I need to replace degrees entrys(strings) with numbers. (1 = Highschool, 2 = Techinical, 3 = Graduate, 4 = Post-Graduate)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

formacao = pd.read_csv("bases/formacao.csv")
formacao['grau'] = formacao.degree
formacao.grau.fillna(0, inplace=True)
formacao.loc[formacao.grau.str.contains('Tecnico|Curso T|Technical|Técnico|Technician|Minor|Technologist',case=False,na=False)] = 2
formacao.loc[formacao.grau.str.contains('Undergraduate|High School|Ensino Médio|Ensino Medio|Cursando|Under graduate',case=False,na=False)] = 1
formacao.loc[formacao.grau.str.contains('Bachelor|Bacharel|Licenciatura|B.S.|College|Engenheiro|Engenharia|Graduate|Ciencia|Ciência|Science|Graduação',case=False,na=False)] = 3
formacao.loc[formacao.grau.str.contains('Master|MBA|Mestrado|Pós|Post|Especialista|Specialist|Specialization|Especialização',case=False,na=False)] = 4
formacao.grau.unique()
```

That is my code, the problem is that sometimes it works. Sometimes it doesn't. I used this exact code earlier and got all the results not yet covered. Then started adding new strings and I got this error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

I closed jupyter and it works again. I change a single letter, and the same error. 
Now, **I know this makes no sense**, but I can't deliver the assignment like that. Not only because it isn't done, but also, how can I know if the teacher will be able to run the code. 
What can possibly be wrong?

Here is the full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-4bad11236a95> in <module>
      1 formacao['grau'] = formacao.degree
      2 formacao.grau.fillna(0, inplace=True)
----> 3 formacao.loc[formacao.grau.str.contains('Tecnico|Curso T|Technical|Técnico|Technician|Minor|Technologist',case=False,na=False)] = 2
      4 formacao.loc[formacao.grau.str.contains('Undergraduate|High School|Ensino Médio|Ensino Medio|Cursando|Under graduate',case=False,na=False)] = 1
      5 formacao.loc[formacao.grau.str.contains('Bachelor|Bacharel|Licenciatura|B.S.|College|Engenheiro|Engenharia|Graduate|Ciencia|Ciência|Science|Graduação',case=False,na=False)] = 3

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   4370         if (name in self._internal_names_set or name in self._metadata or
   4371                 name in self._accessors):
-> 4372             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   4373         else:
   4374             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py in __get__(self, obj, cls)
    131             # we're accessing the attribute of the class, i.e., Dataset.geo
    132             return self._accessor
--> 133         accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
    134         # Replace the property with the accessor object. Inspired by:
    135         # http://www.pydanny.com/cached-property.html

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in __init__(self, data)
   1893 
   1894     def __init__(self, data):
-> 1895         self._validate(data)
   1896         self._is_categorical = is_categorical_dtype(data)
   1897 

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in _validate(data)
   1915             # (instead of test for object dtype), but that isn't practical for
   1916             # performance reasons until we have a str dtype (GH 9343)
-> 1917             raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string "
   1918                                  "values, which use np.object_ dtype in "
   1919                                  "pandas")
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `I change a single letter, and the same error.` <- We can't help unless you tell us **exactly** what you are doing here via a **reproducible** example.

Comment: @Not sure how I can reproduce this. I could